# Spring Boot: Send requests on another port to a custom Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, spring-boot

I want my spring-boot app to listen on a second port (where the "first" one is server.port used for spring-webmvc endpoints) and direct all traffic coming in to "/" on the second port to an implementation of Servlet I have written.  These requests will be json-rpc requests which I want separated from normal service traffic.  How can I achieve this?

I have found code to have the embedded Tomcat listen on another port by adding another Connector like so:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createRpcServerConnector());

    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createRpcServerConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    connector.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("rpc.port")));

    return connector;
}
```

And I have found that you can register another Servlet simply by exposing it as a Bean, like so

```
@Bean
public Servlet rpcServlet() {
    return new RpcServlet();
}
```

However, when exposing a Servlet like this, it simply maps it to a URL pattern on the regular server.port.  I cannot figure out how to connect it to the RPC connector such that "/" on my webmvc port is not trying to process RPC requests, and the RPC port does not forward requests to my `@RestController` methods.

Perhaps this comes from my misunderstanding of Tomcat.  Should I even be using Tomcat for this?  Should I switch to another embedded servlet container provided by spring-boot?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you running these two in a single app and not as two separate apps?

Comment: That's a great question, Tim.  Unfortunately this wasn't my decision.  I have been tasked with implementing it this way.  I think the motivation is to put different types of traffic on different ports for reasons beyond my understanding.

Comment: And what's the motivation for not having two separate applications, each listening on a single port? As @Tim asked, why does it have to be in a single application?

Comment: I believe the intention is to provide two different ways of interacting with the same application.  The RPC services and REST endpoints will both be managing the same type of data and utilize the same business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To isolate a `Connector` for use by a single application, that connector needs to be associated with its own `Service` and then you need to associate the `Context` for the application with that `Service`.

You can set this up in your Spring Boot app by providing your own `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` subclass as a `@Bean` and overriding `getEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat)`. This gives you a chance to make the required configuration changes:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            Server server = tomcat.getServer();

            Service service = new StandardService();
            service.setName("other-port-service");
            Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
            connector.setPort(8081);
            service.addConnector(connector);
            server.addService(service);             

            Engine engine = new StandardEngine();
            service.setContainer(engine);

            Host host = new StandardHost();
            host.setName("other-port-host");
            engine.addChild(host);
            engine.setDefaultHost(host.getName());

            Context context = new StandardContext();
            context.addLifecycleListener(new FixContextListener());
            context.setName("other-port-context");
            context.setPath("");
            host.addChild(context);

            Wrapper wrapper = context.createWrapper();
            wrapper.setServlet(new MyServlet());
            wrapper.setName("other-port-servlet");
            context.addChild(wrapper);
            context.addServletMapping("/", wrapper.getName());

            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}

private static class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }

}
```

With this bean added to your application, http://localhost:8081 should be handled by `MyServlet` and return a response containing "Hello, world".

Comment: I will add to this that in order to get request scoped beans to work properly in requests processed by this servlet, add RequestContextListener to the context, like this:

context.addApplicationEventListener(new RequestContextListener());