# Application with API on one port and admin area on another port

Tags: java, spring-boot, port, vaadin

I have an application with RESTful Web Service running on default port 8080. 
Also there is Vaadin web-apps which is used as Admin area for Spring boot app.
Vaadin admin mapping is `/bo` and Spring Boot REST mappings are `/api`. 
Is it possible to change the port for vaadin mappings to 8081?

UPDATE:
I have maven Spring Boot project with embedded TomCat as a Servlet Container.

Here is my Vaadin control:

```
@SpringUI(path = "/bo")
@Title("Admin Dashboard")
@Theme("dashboard")
public class DashboardUI extends UI {
.....
}
```

Spring boot controls are just like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/simple", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String authSimple() {
    return "Simple";
}
```

I think I need something similar to  I need it in the production. 
Something similar to [Spring Boot: Send requests on another port to a custom Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757588/spring-boot-send-requests-on-another-port-to-a-custom-servlet) but with Vaadin.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Intellij IDEA. But does it make any effect?

Comment: I believe you should be able to setup two different instances of the same server from your IDE, assign different ports to each instance then you can assign those server instances separately to your applications.

Comment: This is a matter of the servlet container you run.