# Adding separate custom Servlet in Vaadin 23 - Spring 2.7.1

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

This question was already asked, however since then all answers (that I could found) are no longer valid.

Essentially I want to implement a website with Vaadin (V23), that communicates with a WebApp via POST requests that is running on another server (physically). To do it, I want to create separate Servlet that would handle the communication (receiving side) with another Server. Let's say, this is not implemneted version:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/communication", name = "QuizServlet", asyncSupported = true)
public class QuizServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendError(400, "Not implemented");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendError(400, "Not implemented");
    }
}
```

The problem is however, that I always get redirected to default dispatcher Servlet, and it seems, regardless of what I do:

1. SpringVaadinServlet was deprecated and no longer exists, extending VaadinServlet does not work.
2. Changing mappings in properties (`vaadin.url-mapping=`) also does not work, I just get redirected to this new mapping in all cases.
3. Trying to do servlets on separate ports yields same redirection on all ports, even if explicitly registering my custom Servlet on the Connector, with separate Sevice (`WebMvcConfigurer` Tomcat configuration). Answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757588/spring-boot-send-requests-on-another-port-to-a-custom-servlet), also too old.
4. Registering servlet directly also does not do anything (by implementing `WebApplicationInitializer`).

There for the question, how to make use of two different servlets with new Vaadin 23 and Spring Boot 2.7.1?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but if communicating with an external application is what you want, then did you consider implementing a standard Spring REST endpoints to handle this communication? That should work seamlessly in a Vaadin app.

Comment: So your Vaadin app is a client calling upon a web app on a different server? Then you **don’t need to write a Servlet**. You need to write Java code that uses a library to make a HTTP call, web client code.

Comment: Well, my app waits for incomming POST request, then authenticates it. If this is authenticated, then it starts communication - namely it sends POST request with JSON and then awaits answer through POST request with another JSON. Essentially it requests from another app to do some process with given JSON and becomes the result after this process is done (may take long time).

Comment: And yes, I have looked into it, and I think that I need both: 1) Servlet to receive and process requests from another server; 2) Some kind of WebClient to send POST requests quickly.

Comment: Your Question does not match your Comments. Edit the Question for clarity.

Comment: So you want to basically reverse-proxy another application? Why do _need_ a servlet? Is this other application provided to you as a servlet and you have to make it run inside your own?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found some kind of a solution to my problem. Namely on startup of my BootAplication, I am also starting the second separate Tomcat server that uses my custom Servlet :

```
@Service
public class QuizServer {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(QuizServer.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void startServer() throws IOException, LifecycleException {
        start();
    }

    private void start() throws IOException, LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        String contextPath = "/";
        String appBase = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();

        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, appBase);
        Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "quizServlet", new QuizServlet());
        ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/*", "quizServlet");

        tomcat.setPort(8085);
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getConnector();
        log.info("Quiz server started");
    }
}
```

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "quizServlet", asyncSupported = true)
public class QuizServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Test");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendError(400, "Not implemented");
    }
}
```

It is a bit crude though, since ideally, it shouldn't require a separate server.